# How to run ng serve without hash links?

Tags: angular

I create simple angular cli application using `ng new` and add to routing following code

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'lands/:landId',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: LandComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], // { useHash: true }
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

If I run `ng serve --port 4200` and go to to `http://mysite.local:4200/lands/xyz` it not works (I see white screen) - but if I add `useHash:true` (commented out in above code) then this `http://mysite.local:4200/#/lands/xyz` works.

I see that problem is that I use parameter `/:landId` (because before it is slash) How to run this using `ng serve` without hash in links?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#browser-url-styles

Comment: @R.Richards yep - thanks for link - I have `<base href="./" />` (to run full-project dist on github pages long time ago)  but it should be changed to `<base href="/" />`- now it works.